# How do I avoid ActiveRecord::UnknownAttributeReference when calling where in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-7

I have a Rails app with an endpoint receiving a structure containing, among other things, a bunch of numbers:

```
=> #<ActionController::Parameters {"list"=>[{"item_id"=>"417", "quantity"=>"5"}, {"item_id"=>"418", "quantity"=>"1"}, {"item_id"=>"416", "quantity"=>"2"}], "controller"=>"items", "action"=>"total"} permitted: false>
```

After doing this stuff with `.require` and `.permit`:

```
  def purchase_list
    params.require(:list).map do |list_entry|
      list_entry.permit(:item_id, :quantity).to_h
    end
  end
```

I extract the stuff I need and store it in a `purchase_list` variable from a method call:

```
[{"item_id"=>"417", "quantity"=>"5"}, {"item_id"=>"418", "quantity"=>"1"}, {"item_id"=>"416", "quantity"=>"2"}]
```

I then want to query my database for `items` records with `id` values matching those `item_id` numbers in the request params. I'm doing this:

```
items = Item.where(id: purchase_list.pluck(:item_id))
```

Then when I try to use `items` in any way, for example just something like this (real functionality omitted for brevity):

```
x = Item.first.id
items.pluck(id: x)
```

It crashes with this error:

```
     ActiveRecord::UnknownAttributeReference:
       Dangerous query method (method whose arguments are used as raw SQL) called with non-attribute argument(s): {:id=>425}.This method should not be called with user-provided values, such as request parameters or model attributes. Known-safe values can be passed by wrapping them in Arel.sql().
```

I've been playing around with `Arel.sql()` to try and make it work some other way, but I can't get it working. It always gives that `ActiveRecord::UnknownAttributeReference` error.

I've also tried converting them to numbers with `to_i` and it won't help.

But from what I've read in the Rails guides and other places, if I'm calling `where` using the "hash conditions" like this `where(id: [x,y,z])`, that's one of the ways of specifying `where` conditions for which Rails should automatically sanitise the inputs to guard against MySQL injections and that sort of thing? I thought only calling `where` with "pure strings" made it vulnerable?

I would be very grateful if someone could explain to me:

1. Why is Rails giving me that error if I'm using an approach for which Rails should sanitise the input to make it safe?
2. How can I accomplish what I'm trying to do? with `Arel.sql()` or any other way?

I'm using versions:

```
ruby "3.0.3"
gem "rails", "~> 7.0.3", ">= 7.0.3.1"
```

Comment: You get this error because ActiveRecord queries are lazily evaluated. This means that the actual query doesn't happen (and ORM doesn't kick in) until you use the value. That's why it breaks on `Item.first.id`

Comment: The error you're getting seems to mean that params are not properly handled. Could you show that part of the code?

Comment: Do you make JSON requests? Do item_id come as string or integer?

Comment: @MikeSzyndel the error comes when I'm running a request spec, or when I'm sending a request in the PostMan API tool. PostMan is sending JSON requests, so item_id come in as string in " " marks, but at one point I tried converting those numbers to integer with to_i and it didn't seem to help.

Comment: @MikeSzyndel I've edited the post to show how I handle params

Comment: But you know JSON supports int and float? Would it be possible to send them as int? Could you try this in Postman?

Comment: @MikeSzyndel Just tried it with numbers without the " " in PostMan.  Same error happens.

Comment: Okay. One other thing is that maybe map is messing it up. This isn't the right way to do it. Is `purchase_list` an instance of `Action Controller Parameters`? If you call `purchase_list.permitted?` is it true?

Comment: @MikeSzyndel `purchase_list` returns an `Array`. Doesn't respond to `permitted?`.  Could that be the problem? Do I need this stuff to be an instance of `Action Controller Parameters` right up until I use it to query the database?

Comment: Try `params.permit(list: [:item_id, :quantity])[:list]`

Comment: @MikeSzyndel It doesn't work. I still get the same error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There must be something you're not showing here. I tried that code locally and it works for me.

Could you try to run this code in Rails console?

```
pry(main)> params = ActionController::Parameters.new({"list"=>[{"item_id"=>"417", "quantity"=>"5"}, {"item_id"=>"418", "quantity"=>"1"}, {"item_id"=>"416", "quantity"=>"2"}], "controller"=>"items", "action"=>"total"})
=> #<ActionController::Parameters {"list"=>[{"item_id"=>"417", "quantity"=>"5"}, {"item_id"=>"418", "quantity"=>"1"}, {"item_id"=>"416", "quantity"=>"2"}], "controller"=>"items", "action"=>"total"} permitted: false>
pry(main)> purchase_list = params.permit(list: [:item_id, :quantity])[:list]
=> [#<ActionController::Parameters {"item_id"=>"417", "quantity"=>"5"} permitted: true>,
 #<ActionController::Parameters {"item_id"=>"418", "quantity"=>"1"} permitted: true>,
 #<ActionController::Parameters {"item_id"=>"416", "quantity"=>"2"} permitted: true>]
pry(main)> ids = purchase_list.pluck(:item_id)
=> ["417", "418", "416"]
pry(main)> Item.where(id: ids)
```

Comment: I think there are syntax errors there.  I replaced `purchase_listparams.permit` with `purchase_list = params.permit` and replaced `Item.where(id: purchase_list.pluck(:item_id))` with `items = Item.where(id: purchase_list)` then I ran `items.pluck(id: 34)` and I got that same error.

Comment: Fixed the code. If it doesn't work as I posted it then I have no idea. Is every AC:Parameters in the array permitted?

Comment: I tried again and run all 4 statements exactly as you now have them, with the `=` syntax correction, and after the 4th one I get `[]`
But don't I then need to do something else to test whether the error appears? Because of the lazy loading thing?

Comment: If you do it in `rails c` it should print out items for you. Please check how, the code was messed up, but now I fixed it and retested

Comment: I've tested it again exactly as you have the 4 statements, `Item.where(id: ids)` returns `[]`

Comment: But it does work! 

Comment: Based on that you need to go back to your controller and make sure everything is the same step by step. After you run `permit` each instance in the array should have `permitted: true`.

Comment: But won't it never show the error right away after `.where` because of lazy loading? If there were database objects in there, and I then tried to do something with them, isn't that when the error will appear?

Comment: sure, then try to print/log the first element returned by where

Comment: Checked in the console, each of the 3 things in the `purchase_list` array return `true` for `permitted?`

Comment: "then try to print/log the first element returned by where" - Ok, I'll try replicating the code in the controller and running my test when I have objects in the test database that should be found by `where`...

Comment: Yeah, sorry, this is as far as I can help given we're on SO. Good luck!

Comment: I tried it again, then did `items.pluck(id: 454)` at the end, and it raised the same error.   :(
I don't know what I'll do.  Thanks anyway for your help.

Comment: Why `pluck(id: 454)`? Pluck take a key name(s) as argument, and you pass a hash? The result of pluck should be an array if ids (strings or integers)!

Comment: Same with `Item.where(id: ids).pluck(id: 454)` still gives the error  :(

Comment: Ah, it seems to work if I do `puts Item.where(id: ids).first.price`
or if I do `x = Item.where(id: ids).first.price`

Comment: And this works: `Item.where(id: ids).pluck(:id)`